# MySQL: List rows who have one but not another many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, join, many-to-many

Not quite sure how to ask or define this, but can't figure it out.

I have three tables like this:

```
persons             person_id, first_name, last_name
hobbies             hobby_id, name
persons_hobbies     person_id, hobby_id
```

I need to make two lists. Persons that have both hobby A and B, and persons that have hobby A but not B. How can I write these two queries? Can't figure out how to do this with joining and all...

Say hobby A has id=3 and hobby B has id=7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
-- Persons that have both hobby A and B
select p.first_name,p.last_name
from persons p
inner join persons_hobbies ph1 on ph1.person_id = p.person_id and ph1.hobby_id = 3
inner join persons_hobbies ph2 on ph2.person_id = p.person_id and ph2.hobby_id = 7;

-- Persons that have hobby A but not B 
select p.first_name,p.last_name
from persons p
inner join persons_hobbies ph1 on ph1.person_id = p.person_id and ph1.hobby_id = 3
left outer join persons_hobbies ph2 on ph2.person_id = p.person_id and ph2.hobby_id = 7
where ph2.person_id is null;
```

Comment: I do have the id, sorry about that. Added example ids in the question now :)

Answer (score 0):

I find this type to be easier to understand and code if you use sub-queries.

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE person_id IN (SELECT person_id FROM person_hobbies WHERE hobby_id ...)
```

But if you must join - Ike nailed it.

Comment: Since I don't know the size of these tables, I think it's safest to assume they are fairly large, in which case the OP is likely to get much better performance using joins than sub-queries.